# ASP.Net MVC 4 Project Folder Architeture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, directory-structure

My ASP.Net MVC 4 Web project have this architeture:

```
App_Data
App_Start
Content
 - css
 - images
 - scripts
Controllers
Helpers
Models
Views
```

I need to create a folder to save temporary files for download and I don't know where I can create that folder. My main doubt is if I create at the *first level* or inside the `App_Data` folder.

I'm just trying to be careful to not compromise the project architeture.

Comment: Do these downloads need to be directly accessible by a web browser? Or is your application going to be the serving the downloads?

Comment: @StevenV no, they will not be seen by the browser. There will be an Action to sent they to the browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't even make it apart of your project. I would use something like [`Path.GetTempFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx) or [`Path.GetTempPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx) and allow the framework to tell me where I can place those temporary files. Keeps your application directories clean and keeps temporary files in a location that could be safely cleaned up periodically (or your application could delete the file when it's done).

Comment: Nice! Is something like that that I want.